# Open collapse from session storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need an open collapse from session storage.
First, I make this with ng-repeat. When we toggle some row, I take $index and set to sessionStorage.
After refresh, I want to open same row (saved in sessionStorage)

This is the function for save to sessionStorage when we click on the row and on init call from storage

```
if(sessionStorage.length){
                $scope.setInterpretation = 'interpretation' + sessionStorage.getItem("indexOfOpenedRow");
            }
$scope.getIndex = function(indexOfRow){
            $scope.fromSessionStorage = false;
            sessionStorage.removeItem("indexOfOpenedRow");
            sessionStorage.setItem("indexOfOpenedRow", indexOfRow);

            $scope.setInterpretation = 'interpretation' + indexOfRow;

        }
```

This is in HTML how I do this

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in datas | filter:search">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <a href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{setInterpretation}}" ng-model="$index" ng-click="getIndex($index)"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !group.$hideRows, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': group.$hideRows }"></span>
           </a>
       </td>
       <td>Test</td>
       <td>Test</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="collapse" id="{{setInterpretation }}">
       <td>Test</td> 
       <td>Test</td> 
       <td>Test</td> 
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

But, this not working, because when I try to set from sessionStorage, evry ng-repeat row get same ID.

How to fix this? thnx

Comment: please try add 'track by $index'  ----> ng-repeat="data in datas | filter:search track by $index"

Comment: @BąQ thnx, i try but not working

Comment: did you noticed that setInterpretation is shared between all elements in datas ? Maybe that's why you think that all $index are the same. Because $index should work fine http://jsfiddle.net/E6aMZ/325/

Comment: When I click on row for open collapse $index is ok, but problem is when I try to set from sessionStorage, all $index is the same

Comment: But you did not post your code to read sessionStorage. You have posted only $scope.getIndex which is setting value of indexOfOpenedRow to the indexOfRow.

Comment: Sry, I edit my q. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try considering this below code. To track of user row expansion from their last session will the screen remain, below code may help you to achieve the same. 

Also please check [this plunker link](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/qMlbeIs4YClOWPmE) for your given example working scenario.

**Controller:**

```
if(sessionStorage.length > 0){
  $scope.tableData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("indexOfOpenedRow"));
}
$scope.getIndex = function(indexOfRow){
  $scope.tableData[indexOfRow].show = !$scope.tableData[indexOfRow].show;
  sessionStorage.removeItem("indexOfOpenedRow");
  sessionStorage.setItem("indexOfOpenedRow", JSON.stringify($scope.tableData));
}
```

**Template:**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="tab in tableData track by $index">
   <tr>
      <td>
          <button ng-click="getIndex($index)">
            {{ tab.show ? '-' : '+'}}
          </button>
      </td>
      <td>{{tab.col1}}</td>
      <td>{{tab.col2}}</td>
      <td>{{tab.col3}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="collapse" ng-if="tab.show">
      <td></td> 
      <td>Test</td> 
      <td>Test</td> 
      <td>Test</td> 
   </tr>
</tbody>
```